# Listing files alphabetically (both files and folders)

Tags: php, file, filesystems

How would I list all the files and folders in a folder alphabetically with PHP?

I used the following for the files `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c`, and `d.txt`, Where `c` is a folder. The problem is that `c` is displayed last instead of after `b.txt` because it is a folder.

I'd also like to be able to check if each is either a file or folder.

```
<?php
    $dir = opendir ("folders");
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        echo "$file <br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of `glob()` is here to help you. Just do:

```
$dir = glob("folders/*");
```

Comment: How could you check which ones are folders?

Comment: Use the `is_file($filename)` and `is_dir($filename)` functions.

Comment: glob has several parameters, so, you can use it twice, first for the folders and next for the files. or use is_file() and is_dir() mentioned above.
http://php.net/glob for the more info
(PHP folks have very useful url shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

Just read the names into an array first instead of printing immediately. Then sort the array, and then do your output.

```
<?php
$dir = opendir ("folders");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    $names[] = $file;
}
sort($names, SORT_STRING);
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo "$name <br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the names into an array first instead of printing immediately. Then sort the array, and then do your output.

```
<?php
    $files = array();
    $dir = opendir ("folders");
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
    sort($files);

    foreach ($files as $f)
        echo "$f <br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code (no need for opendir etc.)

```
$entries = glob("*");
sort($entries); // This is optional depending on your os, on linux it works the way you want w/o the sort
var_dump($entries);

/* Output
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "a.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "b.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "d.txt"
}
*/
```

For the secound part of your question: You the php "is_file" and "is_dir" functions

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = scandir('folders');
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file.'<br />';
}
```